# user name password length

Tags: asp.net

I have a text box for users to add their password and I want to prevent the user from adding one character in the text box ,How Can I do this?

Comment: Adding what character? If you mean don't allow more than x characters, e.g. 10, use the MaxLength property otherwise explain better.

Comment: What you want to do preventing user from adding one character?? what it means?? which character???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a validater something like:

```
<asp:RangeValidator
ControlToValidate="tbox1"
MinimumValue="1"
MaximumValue="100"
Type="Integer"
EnableClientScript="false"
Text="The value must be from 1 to 100!"
runat="server" />
```

or

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
ID="regexTextBox1" 
ControlToValidate="YourTextBoxID"   
runat="server"
ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{1,200}$"
Text="200 characters max" />
```